# Best way to make database connection Permantally in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I read messages from ActiveMQ and insert into database. Messages are too high around 10 per second. What is best way to make database connection. Currently I make connection with database and never close to it.

Should i use connection pooling. what will be benifit.

Comment: I don't believe there are any issues with keeping the connection open, particularly if it is being frequently used. And, I wouldn't expect a connection pool to improve anything in this type of senario.

Comment: Thanks munyul for your answer..Can you do one more help.I receive message in Listener. So does I need to do synchronize my connection object.

Comment: One of the benefits of a connection pool in this situation might be automatic failure recovery; most pools have built-in support to check for stale connections to toss them out. But if you have 10 message listeners abusing the exact same connection at the exact same time right now, you might want to setup a pool with a minimal size of 10 anyway.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal, if there is a chance that multiple threads will access the connection at the same time, then yes you should synchronise it. Or create a new connection for each thread, which in this case you might then consider a connection pool after-all.